# How can I overlay a rainbow gradient over a photographic image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

[image]

How can I make this color effect in Photoshop? Is it a gradient?

Comment: Please update your question to include what you've already tried and what effort you've made. You'll be more likely to get a good answer if you put in some work. Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 4):

1. Convert your source image to greyscale. (Either by desaturating it or converting the image mode to grey scale and then back to CMYK/RGB.)
2. Add a layer above your image.
3. Fill the new layer with a gradient of the colour and angle that you desire. (The example image is a diagonal rainbow.)
4. Set the gradient layer to MULTIPLY in the layers pallette.

Done.

Comment: ...don't forget the blue eyes...

Comment: @Paul: 10/10 for attention to detail. I suppose that would depend on the specific image to be treated, but yes, the blue eyes would need separate attention in this example, probably by adding blue -> cyan circular radial gradients over the top of the rainbow (on the same layer as the rainbow gradient).

Comment: The point 1 is relative, but it is a good start. The photo could be of an albine tiger. Some aditional steps could be a) Just desaturating it, at some degree, not completely and b) playing with the curves of the original image, to achive diferent levels of whiteness and contrast.